# trouble sending a jsf request with missing required fields

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having some trouble for a couple days, and we can't find on the web a good way of solving it. So i I'll put here and hope anyone can help me and others with same problem.

We have a big form with some `p:selectOneMenu` components on it. When the user wants an extra option he can click on the plus button on the side of a component, to be redirected to a new page to create and save on db  the new option.

We made it work very well using a keepAlive function that holds a desired object through the screens. But we have some required fields that are blocking the plus button when blank.

Switching the button to `immediate="true"` doesn't really helped because then the fields are not being passed to the attributes.

---

So what we need is a way of passing the fields to the attributes so we can keep across screens even when some required fields are blank! Does anyone have an idea that might work?

Comment: "keepAlive function"? How exactly? This term is typically used in JSF 1.x + RichFaces context, not in JSF 2.x + PrimeFaces context.

Comment: It's basically a function to hold an object in the session while going to a new form and coming back later. Then we allow the user to create a new option for the combo box and return without loosing the filled fields. Is there any better solution on JSF 2.x ?

Comment: Yes. Just put the bean in the view scope using `@ViewScoped`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let the `required` attribute evaluate `true` only when the save button is really pressed.

```
<c:set var="saveButtonPressed" value="#{not empty param['form:save']}" />

<h:form id="form">
    <p:selectOneMenu ... required="#{saveButtonPressed}" />
    <p:inputText ... required="#{saveButtonPressed}" />
    ...
    <p:commandButton id="save" ... />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Maan that's simple! I'm impressed how it's simple. I spent so much time finding a workaround by putting ajax change listeners inside every single component. This will make the page much more stable. Thank you very muuch!